# How to select data of one column from a Dataset ( in this particular case )?

Tags: programming, dataset, associations

I use Mathematica 11.0.1 on Windows10, consider the following MWE:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];

dsA = {{"id" -> 1,
     "valueA" -> 100,
     "code" -> {
       {"step" -> "navigateTo", "arg" -> "url"},
       {"step" -> "click", "arg" -> "CSS"}}},
    {"id" -> 2,
     "valueA" -> 101,
     "code" -> {
      {"step" -> "navigateTo", "arg" -> "url"},
      {"step" -> "click", "arg" -> "CSS"}
       }}} // ToAssociations //Dataset;

dsB = {{"id" -> 2,
     "valueB" -> 110,
     "code" -> {
       {"step" -> "execute", "arg" -> "JS"},
       {"step" -> "waitForElements", "arg" -> "CSS"}}},
    {"id" -> 3,
     "valueB" -> 111,
     "code" -> {
       {"step" -> "execute", "arg" -> "JS"},
       {"step" -> "waitForElements", "arg" -> "CSS"}}}} // 
   ToAssociations //Dataset;

dsC = ToAssociations[Map[{
      Append[#,
        "code" -> Normal[Join[
           #[["L-code"]],
           #[["R-code"]]
           ]]] // ToAssociations
      } &,
    JoinAcross[dsA, dsB, "id", 
     "KeyCollisionFunction" -> ({"L-" <> #, "R-" <> #} &)]
    ]] // Dataset
```

Now, the query

```
dsA[[All, {"valueA"}]]
```

works as expected, but the query

```
dsC[[All, {"valueA"}]]
```

aborts with message:

```
Message Part::partw,{"valueA"} of ... does not exist.
```

Clearly, I must have done something wrong. I basically want to select id, valueA, valueB and code ( drop code-L, code-R ) from dsC, how can this be done and why the error message?

Note that the following code is a workaround that works in this MWE but would be rather verbose and impractical in the actual code base:

```
dsC = Map[{
      "id" -> #[["id"]],
      "valueA" -> #[["valueA"]],
      "valueB" -> #[["valueB"]],
      "code" -> Join[
         #[["L-code"]],
         #[["R-code"]]] // Normal
      } &,
    JoinAcross[dsA // Normal, dsB // Normal, "id",
     "KeyCollisionFunction" -> ({"L-" <> #, "R-" <> #} &)]] // 
   ToAssociations // Dataset
```

In this case

```
dsC[[All, {"valueA"}]]
```

works OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
JoinAcross[
    dsA, dsB, "id", "KeyCollisionFunction" -> ({"L-" <> #, "R-" <> #} &)
][
    All
  , Append[#, "code" -> Join[#"L-code", #"R-code"]] & /*  
        KeyTake[{"id", "valueA", "valueB", "code"}]
]
```

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why there isn't some kind of `KeyCollisionMergeFunction` which automatically creates `key -> mergeF[{val1 val2}]`? Maybe `JoinAcross` is an abstract concept from db world and what we have is what people outside expect?

Comment: That's what I am after, yes. KeyTake is new for me.

Comment: @niloderoock `#[[{"id",...]]&` would probably work too

Answer (score 5):

If you inspect your dataset with

```
dsC // Normal
```

you will notice that it is a list of a list of associations. Thus:

```
dsC = ToAssociations[
    Map[{Append[#, 
       "code" -> Normal[Join[#[["L-code"]], #[["R-code"]]]]] // 
        ToAssociations} &, 
        JoinAcross[dsA, dsB, "id", 
        "KeyCollisionFunction" -> ({"L-" <> #, "R-" <> #} &)]]] // 
   Flatten // Dataset
```

And it works fine.

Comment: Yes, works indeed.